# How can I get my powershell script to clean-up after itself?

Tags: powershell, datetime, export-to-csv

I am creating a script that will pull user's and specific user attributes from an AD group. When this is complete export that imformations as CSV to a network folder to be pulled by another application.

What I need to actually happen is have it either write over itself with an updated time and date leaving only one file in the network folder to be picked up or leave X past versions at which point it will loop back around and only create 4 new CSV's so there are a few previous versions backlogged.

This is the current PS script I have which works correctly except to the noted issues I'm having

```
# File Path
$Path = "\\filelocker.******\ftp\FTP Archives\*****\Submitted_Reports-Prod"

# Create variable for the date stamp in log file
$LogDate = Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhhmm

# Define CSV and log file location variables
# They have to be on the same location as the script
$Csvfile = $Path + "\******_User_List_$logDate.csv"

# Import Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Set distinguishedName as searchbase, you can use one OU or multiple OUs
# Or use the root domain like DC=exoip,DC=local
# modified to allow AD group and not OU's
$DNs = @(
    #"OU=IAM Testing,DC=as,DC=local"
    "****** New Users Test"
    #"******* - Users"
)

# Create empty array
$AllADUsers = @()

# Loop through every DN
foreach ($DN in $DNs) {
    #$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $DN -Filter * -Properties *
    $Users = get-adgroupmember $DN -recursive | % { $group=$_ 
    get-aduser $_ -Properties *}

    # Add users to array
    $AllADUsers += $Users
}

# Create list
$AllADUsers | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object `
@{Label = "First name"; Expression = { $_.GivenName } },
@{Label = "Last name"; Expression = { $_.Surname } },
@{Label = "UserName"; Expression = { $_.SamAccountName } },
@{Label = "Manager Name"; Expression = { % { (Get-AdUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName } } },
@{Label = "Manager Email"; Expression = { % { (Get-AdUser $_.Manager -Properties Mail).Mail } } },
@{Label = "User Title"; Expression = { $_.Title } },
@{Label = "E-mail"; Expression = { $_.Mail } }|

# Export report to CSV file
Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path $Csvfile -NoTypeInformation #-Delimiter ";"
```

I'm not sure if I need another loop to achieve this or messing with Export-CSV. Right now it just waiting a new file every time the script runs. Which will eventually lead to a lot of clean-up.

type here

Comment: Your code is wasting a lot of time and system resources. [1] Avoid adding to an array with `+=`, instead use syntax `$AllAdUsers = foreach ($DN in $DNs) { .. }` and within the inner loop just output the result of `Get-ADUser`. [2] Don't use `-Properties *` if all you want is a few extra attributes like Manager, Title and EmailAddress. [3] To get the managers name and email address, you are calling `Get-ADUser` twice.. You also do not check if the user actually has something set in its `.Manager` property wich may lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to up your scripting game.
All things pointed by @Theo are valid, and we are incorporating in our script.
I included comments to be easier for you to follow along, make sure to read them.
References are in the bottom.

```
$Path = "\\filelocker.******\ftp\FTP Archives\*****\Submitted_Reports-Prod"

# You can avoid '+' to concatenate strings by puting them in the same string.
# Even expressions like the date can be inlined.
$fileName = "******_User_List_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmm').csv"
$CsvFullName = "$Path\$fileName"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$DNs = @(
    #"OU=IAM Testing,DC=as,DC=local"
    "****** New Users Test"
    #"******* - Users"
)

# ArrayList, or List<> is preferred because you can use .Add() or AddRange() that dramatically increases performance.
# Using List<> also allows you to get fancy with Linq.Enumerable methods, if performance is critical.
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$allAdUserInfo = @()

# Loop through every DN
foreach ($distinguishedName in $DNs) {
    
    # This is a tip, use aliases when testing things on the console and such.
    # Using aliases in scripts can mislead and make it harder to understand, since they can vary from PC to PC.
    
    # Avoid '| ForEach-Object { }' as much as possible. It's terribly slow.
    # Get used with error handling, specially while building AD scripts. A typo in one of the DNs can break the whole thing.
    try {
        foreach ($member in (Get-ADGroupMember $DN -ErrorAction Stop)) {

            # If you are going to create custom property names, consider creating a PSCustomObject.
            # Select-Object and the translation can add overhead.
            # Another tip, while creating property names, avoid spaces as much as possible. It reduces parsing errors.

            # Get-AD* Cmdlets -Properties * is crazy expensive and can cause problems.
            # Ad uses LDAP queries with page sizes, number, and timeout preset. If a timeout happens, you risk breaking the whole thing.
            $adUser = Get-ADUser $member -Properties GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Mail -ErrorAction Stop # SamAccountName is comes as default.
            if ($adUser) {

                # I'm not sure how your domain is configured, but the ones I've worked with Manager e-mail is an user attribute.
                # If so, this step can be skipped.
                $managerInfo = Get-ADUser $adUser.Manager -Properties DisplayName, Mail

                # .Add() returns the number of itens on the collection. [void] will suppress output,
                # like 'Out-Null', but faster.
                [void]$allAdUserInfo.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
                    FirstName    = $adUser.GivenName
                    LastName     = $adUser.LastName
                    UserName     = $adUser.SamAccountName
                    Title        = $adUser.Title
                    EMail        = $adUser.Mail
                    Manager      = $managerInfo.DisplayName
                    ManagerEmail = $managerInfo.Mail
                })
            }
        }    
    }
    catch {
        # Handle the error as you like, you can write a log file, or display it on the screen.
        # $PSItem -eq $_
        Write-Host "Failed processing: $($PSItem.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Checking if the file already exists.
# We are going to create two cases here, one where only one file is allowed, and other where we maintain a backlog of 4 files.

# Case 1:
# Checking if the file exists.
if (Test-Path -Path $CsvFullName) {
    # Removing the file.
    Remove-Item -Path $CsvFullName -Force
}
# Exporting
# I liked the worrying with encoding. That's the spirit.
$allAdUserInfo | Sort-Object -Property 'Name' | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path $CsvFullName -NoTypeInformation

# Case 2:
# Getting a list of all CSV files on that folder.
# You can filter specific names as well.
# The files here are already being ordered by creation date.
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.csv | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime

# Now we want to have only the newest 4 files.
# If you are sure that there's only 5 files there you can do:
$fileList | Select-Object -Last 1 | Remove-Item -Force

# But that's somewhat dangerous. What if there are more files?
# So we will get the first 4 files out, and remove what's left.
$lastFileIndex = $fileList.Count - 1 # Array indexes are 0 - based

# Here we select a Range inside that list.
# We're selecting from the 4th member to the last.
$fileList[3..$lastFileIndex] | Remove-Item

# Get used to check if things are there before saving.
# This last one is a bonus.
# If a file with this name already exists, it will append a '(n)' at the end.
$finalFileBaseName = $fileName.Replace('.csv', '')
$postfixIndex = 1
while (Test-Path -Path "$Path\$finalFileBaseName" -PathType Leaf) { # Leaf -eq File -eq Archive
    $finalFileBaseName = "$fileName ($postfixIndex)"
    $postfixIndex++
}

$allAdUserInfo | Sort-Object -Property 'Name' | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path "$Path\$finalFileBaseName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[Performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3)
[Get AD user in detail](https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/get-aduser/)

Hope it helps.
Happy scripting!

Comment: Thanks you guy's I'm going to take a look thanks for the resource tip This does some time to run so I knew it can be more efficient.